# Json string cannot be parsed or not valid JSONObject

Tags: java, json, gson, org.json

I have searched and tried every example I can on StackOverflow  before posting. Nothing seems to work, so hopefully someone can shed some light on what is going on.

I have a json returning from a WCF Service in UTF-8 format. When the data returns I massage the data to remove the '\n' (caused by BufferedReader to StringBuilder appending) and backslashes if they are there and left with this string:

```
(from Log.d):
D/WEB: "{\"BattleList\":[{\"LiveID\":1,\"BattleID\":1,\"OvxyzID\":1234,\"ChallengerID\":1,\"OpponentID\":2,\"ChallengerName\":\"Tank1\",\"OpponentName\":\"Tank2\",\"TimeChallenged\":\"12-6-2015\",\"IsActive\":1,\"TimeEnded\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}]}"
```

I have tried all the major json parsers to get this to work: gson, json-simple, json-lib, minimal-json. All with the same results 'Cannot be converted to JSONObject' or 'Not a valid Array' or 'Not valid Value', etc.

An exact org.json Exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"BattleList":[{"LiveID":1,"BattleID":1,"OvxyzID":1234,"ChallengerID":1,"OpponentID":2,"ChallengerName":"Tank1","OpponentName":"Tank2","TimeChallenged":"12-6-2015","IsActive":1,"TimeEnded":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
12-12 02:56:12.138 27304-27304/com.myproject W/System.err:     
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
```

Even though the Exception is a typeMismatch I checked to ensure the field names and their respective dataTypes are the same.

However, in all these cases it works if I copy the string and put it in a String variable
    String json = "{\"BattleList\":[{\"LiveID\":1,\"BattleID\":1,\"OvxyzID\":1234,\"ChallengerID\":1,\"OpponentID\":2,\"ChallengerName\":\"Tank1\",\"OpponentName\":\"Tank2\",\"TimeChallenged\":\"12-6-2015\",\"IsActive\":1,\"TimeEnded\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}]}"

org.json was able to create a valid object from the variable, but matching it with what my 'result' variable is..its identical.

I have went to json validators online and using my Notepad++ json plugin, and my returning result is valid.

With Gson, I created a custom Deserializer, what I find interesting is with my returning result the JsonElement only gets the '{' and throws exception. When I use the String variable the JsonElement gets the entire string.

Below are the different ways I have tried to deserialize this. My apologies if this is too much info and not needed.

```
//json-lib
//net.sf.json.JSONObject json = net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(response);

//json-simple
//JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
//org.json.simple.JSONObject json = (org.json.simple.JSONObject)parser.parse(response);
//org.json.simple.JSONObject obj = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(response);
//JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
//JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(response);


//org.json
//JSONObject jsonObj = null;
//try {
//    jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
//} catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
//    e.printStackTrace();
//}
//JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
//JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
//JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("BattleList");


//Gson
//String json = "{\"BattleList\":[{\"LiveID\":1,\"BattleID\":1,\"OvxyzID\":1234,\"ChallengerID\":1,\"OpponentID\":2,\"ChallengerName\":\"Tank1\",\"OpponentName\":\"Tank2\",\"TimeChallenged\":\"12-6-2015\",\"IsActive\":1,\"TimeEnded\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\"}]}";
//Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(BattleList.class, new BattleListDeserializer()).create();
//Type animalType = new TypeToken<BattleList>() {
//}.getType();
//BattleList bl = gson.fromJson(response, animalType);
//GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
//gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(BattleList.class, new BattleListDeserializer());
//Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
//Gson gson = new Gson();
//JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
//JsonObject jObject = parser.parse(jsonFormattedString).getAsJsonObject();

//battleList = gson.fromJson(response, BattleList.class);
```

My BattleList class:

```
public class BattleList {

private List<Battles> activeBattles = new ArrayList<>();

public void addBattle(Battles battle){
    activeBattles.add(battle);
}

public Battles getBattle(int indx){
    return activeBattles.get(indx);
}

public int getCount(){
    return activeBattles.size();
}
```

}

my Battles class:

```
public class Battles {

@SerializedName("LiveID")
public int LiveID;

@SerializedName("BattleID")
public int BattleID;

@SerializedName("OvxyzID")
public int OvxyzID;

@SerializedName("ChallengerID")
public int ChallengerID;

@SerializedName("OpponentID")
public int OpponentID;

@SerializedName("ChallengerName")
public String ChallengerName;

@SerializedName("OpponentName")
public String OpponentName;

@SerializedName("TimeChallenged")
public String TimeChallenged;

@SerializedName("IsActive")
public int IsActive;

@SerializedName("TimeEnded")
public String TimeEnded;
}
```

I am not sure what else to include here, I will modify the question if more is needed.

Basically, what am I doing wrong? Should be pretty straightforward but it's had me blocked for over a week.

Thanks.

Comment: So it's been 5 days and none of the Stack Overflow geniuses have thoughts? #IlluminateConfirmed

Comment: public **java.lang.Object** parse(java.io.Reader in)  Have you tried:    String test = parser.parse(response).toString();   org.json.simple.JSONObject json = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) test